# Filter and get all the details by ID is not showing all the details in the database in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am new to C# and I am currently trying the CRUD operations in it. I have done the Create, Get all details, Update, and Delete. But I am unable to get only and all the details by ID.

I have a database called 'fuel' and in there I have added shedId. For each shed there can be multiple fuels. Now I want to get the fuel details by each shedID.

In here you can see I have 2 data for `shedID:1`
[image: Multiple fuel for shed ID 1]

But when I try to filter the db by shedID, I am getting a response like this. As I am new to C# I don't know how to get it. I searched in the google and couldn't find a solution.
[image: Get by ID]

Please help me with this.

This is the code I have tried

```
    //Get Fuel by each shed id
    [HttpGet("shed/{id}")]
    public JsonResult Get(int id)
    {
        MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(_configuration.GetConnectionString("FuelQueueAppConnection"));

        var filter = Builders<Fuel>.Filter.Eq("shedId", id);

        var dbList = dbClient.GetDatabase("FuelQueue").GetCollection<Fuel>("Fuel").Find(filter);
        return new JsonResult(dbList);
    }
```

Summary - I have a DB called fuels. In there I have many fuels. Each fuel have a shedID and a shedID can have multiple fuels. Now I need to find the fuel list of each shedID. (Like ShedID:1 => 2 fuel details)

Answer (score 1):

I just identified that as the result need to be a list I have to add ToList() after the filtering. I am adding the solution as it might help someone in future.

```
    //Get Fuel by each shed id
    [HttpGet("shed/{id}")]
    public JsonResult Get(int id)
    {
        MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(_configuration.GetConnectionString("FuelQueueAppConnection"));

        var filter = Builders<Fuel>.Filter.Eq("shedId", id);

        var dbList = dbClient.GetDatabase("FuelQueue").GetCollection<Fuel>("Fuel").Find(filter).ToList();
        return new JsonResult(dbList);
    }
```

Thank you all for helping the learners.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two things, don't try and fit the return directly to your object  use the generic  so if the format changes or does not align you still have a return.

Also, if Mongo is returning a list use the .ToList() method.

```
                    //filter by time values less than 2019-11-22 T 06:13:20.000Z
                    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("shed_id", 1);

                    //get the collection from the new db
                    var NewDB = dbNewClient.GetDatabase("FuelQueue");
                    var NewCollection = NewDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Fuel");

                    //get all the documents that satisfy the filter
                    var documents = NewCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

This should return all the records for Shed 1, from there you would have to parse the fuel data from each record.

Comment: Thank You. I'll try like this too